# Fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory while installing jPype

Tags: java, oracle, java-native-interface, jpype

I am trying to install JPype on Ubuntu 13.04. I have Oracle Java 1.7 installed. But when I do so, I get the following error:

```
src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
```

Unlike a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow, the file isn't present on my system i.e.

```
locate jni.h
```

returns nothing. Yes, I have run sudo updatedb before issuing above command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed a JRE and not a JDK.

To compile JNI native code, you need to install a JDK, which comes with the appropriate jni.h header, as well as the OS specific headers.

When you do that, update your include path to

`-I <path_to_jdk>/include -I <path_to_jdk>/include/linux`

Comment: I installed using the file named jdk-7u45-linux-x64.rpm. Should it not install jdk?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't install it properly. :/

Comment: @Samhain I'm trying to build an lib and it giving same missing jni.h exception. where need to set mentioned path..in source file ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is the correct package to be installed!

```
$ sudo aptitude install openjdk-7-source
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate jni.h
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
```