# JPype : fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found

Tags: java-native-interface, setup.py, jpype

Hello I am trying to install JPype-0.5.4.2 using:

```
python setup.py install
```

And I get the following error:

```
In file included from src/native/common/jp_array.cpp:17:
src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am on MacOSX 10.8.5 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966783/1290485) answer worked for me. After editing `def setupInclusion(self):`, I ran `$ python setup.py install` and was successful.

However, if you are on Linux instead, then check to see if you installed the JRE instead of the JDK. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980050/1290485) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`jni.h` is supplied in the `include` directory of the JDK.

Comment: so I need to install JDK in the virtualenv?